# Flask server not visible from my public ip address

Tags: python, flask, webserver

I'm trying to run a flask server on my desktop PC that is publicly available on the internet. I've done the following:

- Set up  a static IP address: 192.168.1.11 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDvmi.png)
- Forwarded port 33 on my router to my static ip address (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxnSM.png)
- Setup flask to use my static ip and port: 33

I'm using the following code as a test webserver

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Test 123 "

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="33")
```

When I open my browser to: http://192.168.1.11:33/ the page displays properly, I see "Test 123"

***My problem comes when trying to connect to my webserver from my public ip address*** When I open my browser to http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:30 (my ip address) all I see is "this site can't be reached, xx.xxx.xxx.xx refused to connect"

I've looked up all the stack overflow answers, I've done the following:

- Turned off windows firewall
- Changed host from "192.168.1.11" to "0.0.0.0"
- Tried a different port

screenshot of code running and error shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTM2G.png

***My question is: What do I need to do to make my flask server visible from my public ip address?***

Comment: Are you trying to connect from a machine within the same network as your server? Your router might or might not allow this. Try connecting from an outside network. You can use your mobile device (connected through a mobile network, not your own WiFi) for a quick test.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, unfortunately I cannot connect through my phone either

Comment: are you using OS X or windows ? if u are using one of them then firewall may be the problem . btw your request from your browser is on port 30 not 33 ( it may be misstyping ) , if you just put your host on 0.0.0.0 you should see your web app .

Comment: where you able to resolve the issue? i am having similar problem

Answer (score 10):

Do you have DHCP activated on your router?
If yes do you see your host as 192.168.1.11 in there?

You have to use '0.0.0.0' on host, that tells Flask to listen on all addresses. 
Try specifying the port with quotes as `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="33")`

Comment: I switched the port to "33", same problem. As for the DCHP, my host wasn't on there before, but I added it now. I still am experiencing the same problem. (This site can't be reached) Here's a screenshot of my router's DCHP page, maybe you can see some problem I don't. http://i.imgur.com/kkv07MI.png

Comment: Even simpler, use `pyngrok` (`pip install pyngrok`) to invoke and manage `ngrok` right from within your `server.py`. [Here's a full Flask example](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#flask), but basically you'd just need to `from pyngrok import ngrok` and then `ngrok.connect(5000)` when you're defining the routes.

Answer (score 4):

change it to app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port="33") to run on your machines IP address.

Documented on the Flask site under "Externally Visible Server" on the Quickstart page:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Add port forwarding to port 33 in your router
Port forwarding explained here
http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/

Comment: I have done both of these, just tested again right now. I still cannot connect. My port is 100% forwarded, tested online. http://i.imgur.com/uZISBqI.png

Comment: From a mobile phone disconnected from wifi.

Comment: @Racialz So you are using mobile data for internet connection and in browser you are trying http://public ip:33 are you trying this way?

Comment: First link broken.

Answer (score 2):

You must give the public ip address/LAN ip address as an argument to app.run method.
When you don't provide host argument, it works fine with http://localhost:8888/ and http://127.0.0.1:888/, but not to access outside the system where you are running the REST services

Following is the example.
app.run(host="192.168.0.29",debug=True, port=8888)

Answer (score 0):

You must try and use the same ip of the development server. Thus, for instance, if the dev server is running on a PC with the address `192.168.1.11`
and port `33`, other clients must point at the same address: `192.168.1.11:33`.
As far as my small experience, it works with the debugger disabled, but I did not check if this is an essential prerequisite.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Every webservice should be run from different port address.Single service is running from a single port.